# System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations validation attributes not working as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have checked for possible solutions to this and haven't been able to get any meaningful solution. I am working on an ASP.NET Web API project and I have a controller route with the below method signature:

```
[HttpPost("cimgAirtimeVending/{msisdn}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseObject>> CIMGAirtimeVending([FromBody] CIMGBillPaymentRequest _cimgAirtimeBillPaymentRequest, [Required, RegularExpression(@"\d{13}")] string msisdn)
```

`CIMGBillPaymentRequest` is a DTO with validations defined on each property as follows:

```
public class CIMGBillPaymentRequest
{
    [Required, RegularExpression(@"\w+"), StringLength(30)]
    public string RequestId { get; set; }
    
    [Required, StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10), RegularExpression(@"\d+")]
    public string DebitAccount { get; set; }
    
    /* [Required, RegularExpression(@"\w+")]
    public string Narration { get; set; } */
    
    [Required]
    public bool IsFees { get; set; }
    
    public List<Charge> Charges { get; set; }
    
    [Required, RegularExpression(@"[\w-]+")]
    public string ProductId { get; set; }
    
    [Required, Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Enter valid ChannelId")]
    public int ChannelId { get; set; }
    
    // [Required, Range(100, 100000, ErrorMessage = "Enter valid Amount (>=100)")]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    
    [Required, RegularExpression(@"\w+")]
    public string CustomerReference { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Charge
{
    // [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10), RegularExpression(@"\d{10,}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"\w+")]
    public string Account { get; set; }
        
    public decimal Fee { get; set; }
}
```

The strange thing is, it appears not all the validation works. If `isFees` is removed from the DTO, it should return a `Required` validation error, but that does not happen. The validation is completely ignored. This does not happen with the `ProductId` property. A `Required` validation error is returned if it is not included in the DTO

Another issue I had was with the `Account` property in the `Charge` class. If you look at the line commented above it, you will see I am using a Regex validation `RegularExpression(@"\d{10,}")]` i.e. to ensure that it is a string of at least 10 digits. However, this validation is completely ignored and I had to use `[RegularExpression(@"\w+")]`.

Any idea what the issue is and possible solution?

Comment: What input values you are trying for `[RegularExpression(@"\d{10,}")]` ? Did you try using it alone, I mean without StringLength attribute?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use it alone. Didn't work. I tried with numeric strings of length >= 10

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?view=net-5.0).

"The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or contains only white-space characters."

"If the MVC data model or entity partial class contains a field that is annotated with the RequiredAttribute attribute, but the page does not contain the property, an error is not raised. Validation occurs only for fields that are submitted to the server."

If you leave out the property entirely then the required validation will not trigger. It will only trigger when explicitly called with null, empty string or string with only whitespace. Therefore I'm assuming the required check on some other fields namely the struct fields also don't work, however when you then check for a range, like with the ChannelId property it will validate the range. The issue here is that a struct can never be null. This means the RequiredAttribute won't work on bool, int, decimal, etc. fields.

In this case when not providing anything for `IsFees` will set the property with the value `default(bool)` the default value for a bool is `false`.

As for the Account field, look at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-5.0)

"You apply the RegularExpressionAttribute attribute to a property when you need to validate values for the property against a regular expression. The regular expression enables you to specify very precisely the format of valid values. The Pattern property contains the regular expression. If the value of the property is null or an empty string (""), the value automatically passes validation for the RegularExpressionAttribute attribute. To validate that the value is not null or an empty string, use the RequiredAttribute attribute."

When providing null, or an empty string to a field with `RegularExpressionAttribute` it will pass the check. This means, for your Account field you need to use `[Required, RegularExpression(@"\d{10,}")]`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually had a feeling that the RequiredAttribute issue was probably due to the fact that the property is a struct. Then the thought of making the property nullable crossed my mind but I am yet to try that out. Do you know if the validation will work if the struct is made nullable? Regarding the RegularExpressionAttribute, the Account field is not meant to be a required field. So I don't know if adding RequiredAttribute will help.

Comment: Update: Just made the isFees property nullable and the RequiredAttribute validation was triggered when I removed it from the DTO. It works!

Comment: Yeah, using a nullable bool is a good solution. As for the Account field, if it is not required then you should not add the attribute, the problem with the ```RegularExpressionAttribute``` is that it just ignores the validation when you provide an empty string. As far as I can tell ```[RegularExpression(@"\d{10,}")]``` should work when called with a string with less than 10 digits or a string where not all characters are digits, e.g. "12345678g9" or "1234"